# Python giving me datetime Value Error from CSV

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, csv, python-datetime

I have one Python file that helps me pull and organize datetime data from a server into a pandas DataFrame, and then export out into a nice and usable CSV. My second Python script needs to read the CSV and analyze the data. If I do not touch the exported CSV, the analysis can read the CSV and runs smoothly. However, as soon as I try to merge a few CSV files together with Excel/other spreadsheet software, I get a datetime error

```
ValueError("time data %r does not match format %r" %    
ValueError: time data '2019-12-26 23:00' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d  %H:%M:%S'
```

Even though, it is a direct copy/paste and still saved as a CSV. Any guru can provide some insight on this matter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty sure this is an Excel issue, not a Python problem.

If you load a .csv that has timestamp strings into Excel, Excel recognizes the datetimes - and formats them. This format seems to default to `MM.DD.YYYY hh:mm` (the date component might be different depending on your locale):
[image]

***If you save the file in Excel, the seconds are removed in the .csv!***

- The only procedure that seems to reliably prevent this behavior is to set a specific date/time format for the respective column, e.g. DD.MM.YYYY hh:mm:ss. AFAIK, You'll have to do this manually for each workbook
- Or perhaps write a macro. In older Excel versions, I had a PERSONAL.XLSB for that; should still work with newer versions, you'll have to put it in `C:\Users\[username]\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Excel\XLSTART`
- you can use .xlsx format instead of .csv, *presumably* you won't loose format information there

Answer (score 0):

I see from the error that not all your CSV files have the same time format.

Some on them are in `[hour:minute]` and some in `[hour:minute:second]`.

```py
ValueError: time data '2019-12-26 23:00' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d  %H:%M:%S'
```

Make sure that datetime fields in all of your CSV matched the same format.

Comment: they are, since all the export are done with the same python file with the same format. I think it has something to do with Excel converting the string. Once I paste some datetime, Excel recognize it is a date and does something internally....

Comment: I suggest converting every datetime field into UNIX time stamp format. you can go back and forth easily between ISO and UNIX (even in Excel).

Comment: "*go back and forth easily between ISO and UNIX (even in Excel)*" - like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46130132/converting-unix-time-into-date-time-via-excel)? that sounds equally painful like the [formatting option](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65034346/10197418) ^^