# Converting UNIX Timestamp in Excel but which timezone?

Tags: excel-formula, unix-timestamp

I've got a data with unix timestamps as the date/time format. I convertet the timestamps with the following line: = A1/86400000+25569 and fomatted the column to the Excel date/time format dd.mm.yyyy hh:mm:ss. My question is, which timezone I got with this conversion? Is this in UTC? I can't find a really helpful answer to my question.

Thanks for helping!

I did try different online services to convert a few unix timestamps of mine but I couldn't really find an answer.

Comment: When all you have is a timestamp, there's no way to tell. You have to ask whomever gave you the spreadsheet.

Comment: Agree to @Someprogrammerdude however try to look on these links : **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2853977)** & **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46130132)**