# Date conversion to local date time

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I have UTC date variable:

```
let d = '/Date(1538560800000+0200)/';
```

I tried to convert this to my local time, without success:

```
moment(accessGroup.TimeOn).toDate() // result: Wed Oct 03 2018 12:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)
moment(d).local().format("DD-MM-YYYY hh-mm-ss"); // result: "03-10-2018 12-00-00"
moment.utc(d).local().format("DD-MM-YYYY hh-mm-ss"); // result: "03-10-2018 12-00-00"
```

I want to get my local time 14:00:00. What is the proper way to do that ?

Comment: What timezone are you in?

Comment: Currently I am time zone which is +2 hour compare with UTC. Because of that I need to see 14:00.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When creating a moment from a string, we first check if the string
>   matches known **ISO 8601** formats, we then check if the string matches
>   the **RFC 2822** Date time format before dropping to the fall back of new
>   Date(string) if a known format is not found.

Moment accepts the ISO 8601 and RFC 2822 formats for string parameters, and your input `/Date(1538560800000+0200)/` is neither. Still, when you pass this to `moment`, it tries to convert this to a string and ends up extracting the possible timestamp parameter, which is `1538560800000`. This can be seen in the following code, as both end up as the same values ..

```
let d = '/Date(1538560800000+0200)/'
moment(d).toString() // Wed Oct 03 2018 12:00:00 GMT+0200
moment(1538560800000).toString() // Wed Oct 03 2018 12:00:00 GMT+0200
```

`1538560800000` when converted to GMT is Wed Oct 03 2018 10:00:00 GMT+0000, hence the output of the following code ..

```
moment.utc(d).toString() // Wed Oct 03 2018 10:00:00 GMT+0000
```

So, under no circumstance you're ever going to get the time as 14:00:00 as this timestamp does not represent that. And timestamps are always absolute (in GMT), there is [no such thing as a local timestamp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2853977/unix-timestamp-always-in-gmt).

---

I feel the gap here is your **wrong interpretation** of the input string, you're thinking ..

- Convert `1538560800000` to local datetime, which is 3rd October, 12:00:00 (local)
- Add `+0200` hours to it, which means turn it to 3rd October, 14:00:00

But, the **correct way** to read it is ..

- Convert `1538560800000` to datetime, which is 3rd October, 10:00:00 (absolute/GMT)
- `+0200` represents the timezone of the source which is `GMT+0200`.

Again, the first interpretation is wrong for the reason mentioned above - **unix timestamps are always in GMT**, they are never in local timezones.

Comment: thanks, the main problem was then in date format, I get from the server :)

Answer (score 0):

I have created jsfiddle as well: http://jsfiddle.net/csinghal/dp7rzmw5/34811/

and same code as below for all format:

```
 var localDate = new Date(1538560800000+0200);
 var utcFormat = moment(localDate).utc().format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS');
 var localFormat = moment.utc(utcFormat, 'YYYY-MM-DD 
 HH:MM:SS').local().format('MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm a');
 console.log('LocalDate: ', localDate);
 console.log('utcFormat: ', utcFormat);
 console.log('localFormat: ', localFormat);
```

Comment: This works, for your example, but how to do that for my UTC time  "/Date(1538560800000+0200)/"

Comment: No, I get result: '10/03/2018 12:00 pm', I should get '14:00' since '/Date(1538560800000+0200)/' is UTC time.